# can the jsp response be cached in the browser that can prevent jsp from executing on the next request?

Tags: java, jsp, caching

just wanted to ask a very simple information.
Does a browser by default, or after using certain response headers, cache the generated output of a jsp page into its cache and then present me with the cached output instead of a dynamic output from jsp the next time it is requested.
If I am correct jsp is a servlet that gets executed in the container and then the html is generated as a response(most of the time).
And I am not talking about caching the response in any container specific scope, that is altogether different, but caching the generated html in the browser cache.

Please suggest if the question is unclear.

Comment: In my experience the cache of the browser is depends on the url.If once the page loaded for the browser will keep the page in cache. If the same url came with some other content then also (Not always) we can see the old page. So new changes will reflect if we refresh page with clearing cache or changing url by adding some query string value to the page(example:-wwww.myurl.com?someblablabla).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the http headers set by the server. By default for a jsp page there is going to be something like:

```
cache-control: no-cache
```

so the jsp will not be cached. Of course the jsp can set the http headers itself to allow the caching.

See for example:

http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html